# C++ 2d array doesn't display

Tags: c++, arrays, types, multidimensional-array, grid

I have a 2d array filled with global variables.

```
#define GRID_WIDTH 19
#define GRID_HEIGHT 10
char grid[GRID_WIDTH][GRID_HEIGHT];
```

Later in the code i use this 2d array

```
void Grid::ResetGrid()
{
    // Empty the console screen
    system("cls");

    // Fills the grid with '#' walls
    for (int i=0; i<GRID_WIDTH; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <GRID_HEIGHT; j++)
            grid[i][j] = '#';
    }
    ir = 2;
}
```

While I'm running the program, i use watches and breakpoints. In the beginning the watch on grid said:

```
Name:  grid
Value: [0] "###################"
           [0] '#'
           [1] '#'
           [2] '#' 
//and so on, i could expand it and look at every part of the array


type: char
```

but now it's broken and it only shows this:

```
Name:  grid
Value: {...}
type: Grid
```

The strange thing is I didn't change the array code, only wrote code lines of compare to what's inside the array.

The code of printing it to the console:

```
void Grid::PrintGrid(int currentX, int currentY )
{
    // Empty the console screen
    system("cls");

    // Displays the finished maze to the screen.
    for (int y=0; y <  GRID_HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for (int x=0; x <  GRID_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            cout << grid[x][y];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    // Just for testing, which direction and on what position the solver is
    cout << ir << "    " << currentX << "," << currentY;
}
```

**The question is:**
Why I can't see the information in the 2d array anymore in the watch or when I hoofer over?
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Show us the code that prints to the terminal

Comment: Argh `#define` and C arrays are you sure you code in C++?

Comment: even with const int GRID_HEIGHT = 10; it doesn't work anymore

Comment: `y <= GRID_HEIGHT` and `x <= GRID_WIDTH` is incorrect your going out of the array bounds.

Comment: even when I stay in bounds it still doesn't work

Comment: Is the output correct? or are you just looking at your IDE?

Comment: The output is correct, but I'm wondering why the array isn't shown properly in the watch.

Comment: `Value: {...}` is a perfectly fine format to display an array. What your seeing is ellipsis and truncation. Normally you can simply click or hover onto it and you will get more information.

Comment: That's the problem. Normally you should get more information. But it only displays {...} even when you hoover over it.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Visual-studio? eclipse?

Comment: Visual studio 2010 ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was why I couldn't see my 2d array anymore in the watch.
It's working again. Don't know what was wrong. But the image below shows the correct use of the watch. I use this to check the information inside the 2d array. But it didn't show information for a while just grid {...} instead of grid 0x00 char (* grid)[25] and then the information about the rows and columns.

[image: this watch on the grid didn't work for a while]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem happens to your codes posted out, because I just tested them in my visual stuido 2008, they runs well by your printGrid function, except varable ir I defined it gloably, and your printGrid function double defined x, and y, you defined it in function head, but in the loop, using for (int x...), which means no sense..

the result just come from the printGird is like this:

```
###################
###################
###################
###################
###################
###################
###################
###################
###################
###################
2    3,4请按任意键继续. . .
```

3, 4 is the value of x, y which passed in printGrid when using it.

Comment: Your right. I gife the methode x and y, so i can see what the current pos is, but i use the same name for the loop, and that isn't right. It's funny that it did work all the time. The ir is defined globaly. The SetGrid() function, where I didn't paste the code of that method here. Shows a more logic grid.

Comment: the re-definition of a variable (which has been defined outside the loop) in the loop will always be accepted, since the variable redefined will only be used in the loop.

Comment: I think you need to debug your functions step by step to check where the tricky happens, it is an original way to find out bugs of your codes. And it is very easy to use visual to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your print code is going out of the bounds of the array. Much like when you're filling the array, you should use

```
for (int y=0; y < GRID_HEIGHT; ++y)
{
    for (int x=0; x < GRID_WIDTH; ++x)
    {
```

That may be the cause of your faulty print.

Comment: This isn't the problem, it's about why it isn't showing the information of the array anymore. But I changed this on my code.